# Can I specif the detail field when I have an elasticsearch index exception?

Tags: elasticsearch

I got an error message when I try to index elasticsearch:
got response `{'took': 1, 'errors': True, 'items': [{'index': {'_index': 'mapstore-development-products', '_type': 'product', '_id': '776896', 'status': 400, 'error': {'type': 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'reason': 'failed to parse', 'caused_by': {'type': 'number_format_exception', 'reason': 'empty String'}}}}]}`

Is there any way that I can know which specific fields are empty from this return result?

Comment: Do you have mapping document? and also the document that you are trying to index?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by (1) not creating an index mapping before posting the first record (2) You have a field that is empty (string) for your first record, which later you want it to be number.

Elasticsearch will dynamically assign types to your fields if you do not specify your mapping in advance. I don't think you should find the specific empty string field. Instead, you should create your mapping for your index before posting the first record so this problem should be resolved. For your case, you might need to create a new index with correct mapping and then reindex.

See this:

1. https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-resolve-numberformatexception-issues-caused-by-an-empty-string/5633
2. https://medium.com/@eyaldahari/reindex-elasticsearch-documents-is-easier-than-ever-103f63d411c